# passing with AJAX to php include

Tags: php, ajax

I need to get the following code to pass the $Bus_Account_ID and the $Usr_ID to the include file rating2.php

```
    $Bus_Account_ID=733;
    $Usr_ID=3;
```

I am not familar with AJAX so learning here.
I believe that this is the line passing to the include but I don't know what is happening with "attrVal"

> ```
> data: 'postID='+attrVal+'&ratingPoints='+val,
> ```

```
   $(function() {
    var value = "<?php echo $total_points ?>"; 

    $("#rating_star").codexworld_rating_widget({
        starLength: '5',
        initialValue: value,
        callbackFunctionName: 'processRating',
        imageDirectory: 'images/',
        inputAttr: 'postID'
    });
});

function processRating(val, attrVal){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'rating2.php',
        data: 'postID='+attrVal+'&ratingPoints='+val,
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'ok') {

                $('#avgrat').text(data.total_points);
                $('#totalrat').text(data.rating_number);
            }else{
                alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

postid shows in only 3 place in the above and here

```
 <input name="rating" value="0" id="rating_star" type="hidden" postID="1" />
```

This is what is being called on the include file

```
$postID = $_POST['postID']; /* BUSINESS ID */
```

How to I call the $Bus_Account_ID and the $Usr_ID?

Comment: `data: 'postID='+attrVal+'&ratingPoints='+val,` should be like this `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

Comment: @FrayneKonok - huh? name: John? location: Boston? How OP has it will work just fine (syntactically)

Comment: Change `data: 'postID='+attrVal+'&ratingPoints='+val,` to `data: 'postID=' + attrVal + '&ratingPoints=' + val + '&userID=<?php echo $Usr_ID; ?>&busAccountID=<?php echo $Bus_Account_ID; ?>',` and you can access those in `rating2.php` using `$_POST['userID']` and `$_POST['busAccountID']` respectively. See how that goes.

Comment: Same issue, where on the page should the $Usr_ID be located? It is not finding that variable. I have it in 2 places top in the 1st php and then in the body in another php, the body is where the $busAccountID is pulling it from but it will not pull the $userid

Answer (score 1):

You have the problem with passing the data here.., You need to maintain the format like this: `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'rating2.php',
        data: 'postID='+attrVal+'&ratingPoints='+val,
```

So change the data by,

```
data: { postID: attrVal, ratingPoints: val, Usr_ID : "<?php echo $Usr_ID;?>", Bus_Account_ID : "<?php echo $Bus_Account_ID;?>" }
```

Comment: I did change that:  data: {postID: attrVal, ratingPoints: val}, and also added <?php $Bus_Account_ID=733;?> into the body and it allowed me to pass the $Bus_Account_ID, but how do I add the $Usr_ID to pass?

Comment: so you want to pass useid and busaccid?

Comment: Yes, passing 2 variables $Bus_Account_ID and $Usr_ID, I have the Bus one working and a little stuck on the Usr. I did get this far: data: {postID: attrVal, ratingPoints: val, userID: 3}, and it works but I need the "3" to be a variable

Comment: I don't understand, why 3 as a variable?

Comment: see the updates and please use valid variable name. I am now on mobile so cant make it properly.

Comment: this is the system.. I think you understand.

Comment: The userid : "<?php echo $userid;?>" doesn't work, if I do this it does: userID: "<?php echo $userid=3; ?>".  Question - do I still need all of this if I have sessions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113096/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-harkly).